# How to access values outside of axios request?

Tags: javascript, axios

Very easy question.  When I run console.log on the jsonPayload in line 6, I see the expected output.  When I run console.log again on jsonPayload in the last line, it returns an empty {}.  How do I access the payload outside of the initial request?

```
var jsonPayload = {}
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/tools')
.then(function (response) {
  jsonPayload = response.data[0]

  // this returns the expected payload
  console.log(jsonPayload)
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error)
})

// this returns empty {}
console.log(jsonPayload)
```

Comment: The function you are calling might be asynchronous hence the first statement doesn't synchronize with your logging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why you would like to access the `jsonPayload` outside of the axios get call, but I do know why you are receiving a log of `{}` from the outside `console.log()`.

```
axios.get()
```

The above method will return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). This promise allows you to protect your next process from receiving empty data.

Inside the `.then()` method, you are able to retrieve the data that is sent back to you from the `axios.get()` call. However, this data cannot reach you until the process of retrieving data from the API, is complete.

This is where you are running into your issue. The `console.log()` outside of the `.then()` method is triggering before the completion of the ajax call.

You could also look into using ES7 `async` and `await`. This allows you to write these `axios` calls without the `.then()`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this because the request is processed *asynchronously*.

Comment: I'm not sure why I would not be able to grab a value from an API call and use it elsewhere.  Maybe I need to switch to a more simple requests library?

Answer (score 0):

As @d3L answered, you're limited to handle the response within the `callback` passed to `.then`. However, after ES8 you can use `async / await` which is an alternative to using typical Promise handling with callbacks. Is still asynchronous, but looks synchronous:

```
(async function() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/tools');
    console.log(response.data[0])
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
```

Note whether you're running it on node or the browser, the engine might not support it, so you might need to transpile the code using [babel](https://babeljs.io/).