# How to properly write a for loop using the request from an axios request in js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to write a for loop that builds a dictionary for each object returned in the axios request.

My understanding is that the logic to "do stuff" with the returned object must be contained with axios '.then' block.

Here is my attempt at trying this (coming from a python background, so probably lots of errors here)

```
var jsonPayload = {}
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/tools')
.then(function (response) {
  jsonPayload = response.data
  console.log(jsonPayload)
  const children = [];
  jsonPayload.forEach(item => {
    const dict = {
       name: item.name,
       path: item.path,
       meta:  {
           label: item.label,
           link: item.link,
       },
       component: lazyLoading('testitem/basic'),
    }
    children.push(dict);
});

})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error)
})
```

THIS is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
const state = {
  items: [
    {
      name: 'android',
      path: '/android',
      meta: {
        icon: 'fa-tachometer',
        link: 'android/index.vue'
      },
 children: [
    {
      name: 'jsonResponse_name',
      path: 'jsonResponse_path',
      meta: {
        label: 'jsonResponse_label',
        link: 'jsonResponse_link'
      },
      component: lazyLoading('test')
    },
    {
      name: 'jsonResponse_name',
      path: 'jsonResponse_path',
      meta: {
        label: 'jsonResponse_label',
        link: 'jsonResponse_link'
      },
      component: lazyLoading('test')
    },
    {
      name: 'jsonResponse_name',
      path: 'jsonResponse_path',
      meta: {
        label: 'jsonResponse_label',
        link: 'jsonResponse_link'
      },
      component: lazyLoading('test')
    },
  ]
},
```

not sure if this is helpful: router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import menuModule from 'vuex-store/modules/menu'
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'hash', // Demo is living in GitHub.io, so required!
  linkActiveClass: 'is-active',
  scrollBehavior: () => ({ y: 0 }),
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'Home',
      path: '/',
      component: require('../views/Home')
    },
    {
      name: 'Login',
      path: '/login',
      component: require('../views/auth/Login')
    },
    ...generateRoutesFromMenu(menuModule.state.items),
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/'
    }
  ]
})

// Menu should have 2 levels.
function generateRoutesFromMenu (menu = [], routes = []) {
  for (let i = 0, l = menu.length; i < l; i++) {
    let item = menu[i]
    if (item.path) {
      routes.push(item)
    }
    if (!item.component) {
      generateRoutesFromMenu(item.children, routes)
    }
  }
  return routes
}
```

Comment: What is `lazyLoading`? Do you have an example of `jsonPayload`? I don't understand how `items` comes into play.

Comment: this is store/modules/menu/index.js in vue.js project

Comment: for what i can extract from the result, @david is trying to dinamically load routes for its Vue Router instance from a json response object. Dear david, your question needs a lot more explaining, for starters, how are you declaring the router, etc.

Comment: i updated with the router if that helps?

Comment: let me know what other information you might need, really the root of my question is just how to create a dictionary for each object returned in an api request in js.

Comment: You're building the array of objects, but it's local to the `then` clause, so it's not winding up where you need it.

Comment: i dont think i have a clear understanding of how axios works, i was told that i can't access the request object outside of then clause, so that is why i moved all my logic inside the then block

Comment: so when your .then is done, does `jsonPayload` in fact equal `response.data`? if so, you should operate your forEach on jsonPayload outside the .then -- you cannot access the object itself once then is done, but you can access the response if you save it to a variable.

Comment: i dont know how to do what you are saying

Comment: A few days ago when I first started playing with axios I was trying to save the response.data and be able to access it outside of the 'then' block but was told that that is not because it is asynchronous. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858453/how-to-access-values-outside-of-axios-request?noredirect=1#comment84720428_48858453

Comment: in your previous question, the console.log that returned empty did so because of timing, not because it is impossible. `.then` means that javascript will go on to evaluate the next expression before coming back to finish whatever is inside the then. So jsonPayload had not been assigned *yet*, but it will be soon. https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript

Comment: ahh okay that makes sense